# Window background is transparent but content is visible

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create a page so that the window is transparent but the content is visible.
How to android studio emulator

After all, Studio can see the emulator, but I'm trying to make it transparent (opacity), but along with the window, transparent content
How to make it look like an emulator:
https://server-js.teleweb.repl.co/download.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry, _what exactly needs to be transparent_? The emulator? The browser window? And what should be behind the browser window in the emulator? I'm very confused.

Comment: Set `transparent: true` when initialising BrowserWindow: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#create-transparent-windows (nb: this has limitations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I found a solution myself, made a web page - I set a transparent background for it, and when creating the window I set these parameters:

frame: false

transparent: true

By the way, please note that if frame is set to true, then you will not get the expected result.

Here is a video (this is me creating a smartphone emulator):
https://indexeddb.teleweb.repl.co/video.mp4